# How to select the current parameter of a function in vim

Tags: python, vim, editor, vi

Using VIM to code in Python I often have to change or delete the parameters of functions.
I expected to find a command like `ci,` to select the text between two commas. Somehow like selecting between matching parentheses or brackets with `ci"` and `ci(`.

```
def function1(a,b,delete_me, c):
    pass

def function2(a,b,delete_me):
    pass

def function3(a,b,delete_me=[1,2,3]):
    pass
```

How can I achieve the expected result efficient with VIM giving the cursor points to the desired parameter already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter matching is difficult (especially with constructs like nested function calls and arrays) as it depends on the underlying syntax. That's why there's no built-in *inner / outer parameter* text object.

I use the [argtextobj.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2699), which works fairly well.

Comment: one of my favorite plugins now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a builtin command for this but here are some examples which might help.

Selecting text:

`ve` -- end of word boundary
`vE` -- end of line

Deleting:

`de` -- delete until end of word
`dE` -- delete until end of line

Some regex magic could also do the work, if you have to remove a bunch of identical things.
`:%s/\,d.*\]//g` -- Replace anything with that begins with `,d` and ends in `]` with `""`

```
def function3(a,b,delete_me=[1,2,3]):
    pass
```

Turns into

```
def function3(a,b):
    pass
```

Comment: `E` is until the next white space, not end of line, right?

Answer (score 1):

For simple parameters, `ciw` (change inside word) is equivalent.

In your third example, if your cursor is at the start of the parameter then `cf]` (change to find `]`) will work.